# CNAME is redirecting to my host page

Tags: dns, cname, centos-web-panel

I have a website hosted on the following path: mywebsite.com/test with the following DNS

```
mywebsite.com            A   1.2.3.4 (host ip)
host.mywebsite.com       A   1.2.3.4 (host ip)
```

On another domain I'm trying to make a subdomain CNAME redirect to this page using the following:

```
link.myotherdomain.com   CNAME .  mywebsite.com/test
```

However when I access  link.myotherdomain.com  it shows the host.mywebsite.com instead of mywebsite.com

I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CNAME record cannot include path. It only for domin to domain.
This setting will work.

```
link.myotherdomain.com.   CNAME   mywebsite.com.
```

---

If configured properly, all of `mywebsite.com` `host.mywebsite.com` `link.myotherdomain.com` are resolve to `1.2.3.4`, then the following HTTP request is sent to IP address `1.2.3.4`.

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: link.myotherdomain.com
......(omit)
```

Now, the most suspiicious element is the Virtual Host setting of webserver.
This is a function of the web server that behaves as if it is a different server according to the Host value in the request header.

To survey about Virtual Host, the following might be the most simple method.

- `curl -H 'Host:mywebsite.com' http://1.2.3.4/test` // this will ok
- `curl -H 'Host:link.myotherdomain.com' http://1.2.3.4/test` // this will not ok if Virtual Host enabled

Comment: Hello!

Sure that's how I'm using it however if I try to access mywebsite.com/test on the browser I see the message "File not Found".

I think it's redirecting to the wrong folder of my server, but I don't know where I can change it

Comment: I added my answer. Isn't your web server enabled the Virtual Host setting?